# Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated

Tags: java, mysql

In a maven-java-sql project using hibernate, when I try to run the project this error message appears. The MySQL server is running but the the maven-java project is not able to comunicate with the MySQL server. I am using the Apache NetBeans IDE and Workbench as the server tool. Here is my persistence class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence              http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="Persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <!-- Persistence provider -->
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/technikon"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

the error message

[image]

Comment: That's just a warning. Looks like the real problem is "Unknown database 'technikon'"

Comment: what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of textual information. Post the error output as code-formatted text.

Comment: ...and [here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Also see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'technikon'

So, you will need to connect to your RDBMS via Workbench (or CLI or whatever) and run

```
show databases;
```

See what databases you are finding in the list (beware db names like `Technikon`) and change your settings accordingly.